# D3js нумерация строк в наборе rect

Tags: svg, d3.js

Как мне пронумеровать строки если есть такой json

```
var json = [{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg11","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg12","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg13","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg14","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg15","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg16","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg17","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg18","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":490,"svgCol":8},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg19","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":560,"svgCol":9},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg21","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg22","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg23","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg24","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg25","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg26","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg27","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg28","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":490,"svgCol":8},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg29","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":560,"svgCol":9},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg31","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg32","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg33","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg34","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg35","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg36","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg37","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7}]
```

и вот как я делаю набор квадратов

```js
d3.json(url, function(json) {

  var canvas = d3.selectAll("#test")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg1")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 800);


  var rects = canvas
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(json)
    .enter()
    .append('rect', '1')
    .attr({
      'x': function(data, index) {
        return data.svgX;
      },
      'y': function(data, index) {
        return data.svgY;
      },
      'id': function(data, index) {
        return data.svgId
      },
      'width': function(data, index) {
        return 50
      },
      'height': function(data, index) {
        return 50
      },
      'fill': function(data, index) {
        return '#006699'
      },

    })
})
```

но вот как сначала каждой строки проставить номер строки?

Answer (score 1):

Как известно d3 расшифровывается как "Data-Driven Documents". Данные управляют документом. Соответственно, вам сначала нужно привести в порядок ваши данные. Положим данные в двумерный массив, в котором каждый дочерний массив содержит данные только этой строки.

```
var rows = d3.max(json, row => row.svgY) / STEP + 1;

var data = Array.apply(null, new Array(rows)).map(() => []);

json.forEach(row => {
  rowBasesJson[row.svgY / STEP].push(row);
})
```

А теперь дело за малым - просто правильно отобразить данные.

```js
var json = [{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg11","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg12","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg13","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg14","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg15","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg16","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg17","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg18","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":490,"svgCol":8},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg19","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":560,"svgCol":9},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg21","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg22","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg23","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg24","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg25","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg26","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg27","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg28","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":490,"svgCol":8},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg29","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":560,"svgCol":9},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg31","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg32","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg33","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg34","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg35","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg36","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg37","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7}]

const STEP = 70;
const ROW =  50;
const COLOR = '#006699';

var rows = d3.max(json, row => row.svgY) / STEP + 1;

var data2x = Array.apply(null, new Array(rows)).map(() => []);
json.forEach(row => {
  data2x[row.svgY / STEP].push(row);
})

var svg = d3.selectAll("#test")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 600)
;

var gEnter = svg
  .selectAll('g.row')
  .data(data2x)
  .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'row')
;

gEnter
  .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'row-number')
    .attr('x', ROW / 2)
    .attr('y', (d, i) => i*STEP + STEP / 2)
    .text((d, i) => i)
  ;

gEnter
  .each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .selectAll('rect.item')
      .data(d)
      .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'item')
        .attr({
            'x':  d => d.svgX + STEP,
            'y':  d => d.svgY,
            'id': d => d.svgId,
            'width': ROW,
            'height': ROW,
            'fill': COLOR
        })
  })
```

```css
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.chart {
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="chart"></div>
```

Каждую строку мы кладём в отдельный контейнер `g`. А `d3` нам любезно предоставляет номер каждого дочернего массива. Воспользуемся этим и в каждом контейнере `g` создадим текстовый узел с номером строки. Ну а дальше пройдёмся по каждому массиву и создадим квадраты.